# Prove that $-\lfloor x+1 \rfloor = \lfloor -x \rfloor$ for all real $x$ not an integer

Tags: ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\lfloor x \rfloor$ be the greatest integer lower bound of any real number $x$. Prove that if a real $x$ is not an integer, then
$$-\lfloor x+1 \rfloor = \lfloor -x \rfloor.$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $n=\lfloor x\rfloor$ then we have
$$n<x<n+1$$
so

$$n+1<x+1<n+2\implies \lfloor x+1\rfloor=n+1$$
and

$$-n>-x>-n-1\implies \lfloor -x\rfloor =-n-1$$
and the result follows.